# Pass PHP Variable into Jquery popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following setup:
JQuery:

```
$('.btn-setting').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
```

Which opens a HTML file as a Dialog box, the problem is that I cannot pass any PHP variables onto the page for reference:

```
<a href="<?= echo $UserID; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-setting">Click for dialog</a>
```

Anyone suggest a method to enable me to do so?

---

Alright. The problem is now, i'm viewing the source of the page.. Yet, it's showing what i'm expecting, now When I click the button to bring up the dialog box, it's showing different data...

Not recommended I know, but heres a live:

> 92.236.219.136/Admin/
>
> User: Stack
>
> Pass: stack

Comment: `<?= echo` doesn't look right, `<?=` is `echo` already.

Comment: Are you trying to pass PHP into the modal window? Or just that link href?

Comment: @Revent I'm trying to pass a PHP variable into the modal window, so from User_Settings.php I can query the database to make  changes to a user account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most robust way, especially if you want to pass more than just one string:

```
<?php

// Call this function to pass an object to the JS code
function php_vars_to_js($id, $obj) {
  echo "<script id='$id' type='text/php_data'>";
  echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( obj ) );
  echo '</script>';
}

// for examlpe
php_vars_to_js( "php_vars", array("a_string" => "foo", "a_num" => 12 ) );
```

And then read it this way:

```
var php_vars = $.jsonDecode( $("php_vars").text() );
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that this is being queried from a HTML/PHP page included, the entire content is not being creating by jquery

Comment: I don't understand your comment. This function is just a safe way to pass objects from the server to the client. You can call it multiple time, with different ids, and assign the resulting object to whatever variable you want

Comment: Would it be alright if I show you a live version? Because i've encountered a weird problem.. On  view source, i'm getting the correct information in the source. When I click, it doesn't display the same as the source

Comment: Sure, link the example

Comment: I have updated my question with a URL, sorry that it's an IP. It's a portforwarded web server which i'm locally testing, once logged in It's under "Developer List"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40146/discussion-between-raffaele-and-sophie-mackeral)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the passed `href` in jQuery like this:

```
$('.btn-setting').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var passedValue = $(this).attr('href');
    // passedValue contains your <?=$UserID?> from the link
    // ...
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: How would I beable to store this as a PHP var?

Comment: you'd need to send it to PHP using ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo $UserID; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-setting">Click for dialog</a>
```

you were echoing the return of echo

Comment: That's not the question at all.

Comment: The question is a method to allow him to pass php variables to the output. Looking at the code, that's not working, so that's why I suggested another scripting 'method'
"the problem is that I cannot pass any PHP variables onto the page"

Comment: @Mazzy two things, 1) her* and 2) Already tried using echos within the anchor reference, doesn't work.

Comment: 1. Have you looked at the source after you ran it?
2. var_dump($UserID);

Answer (score 0):

You can use tha data attribute, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $UserID; ?>" data-variable1="<?php echo $UserID; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-setting">Click for dialog</a>
```

And in your JS:

```
$('.btn-setting').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var1 = $(this).attr("data-variable1"); // Here is your PHP Variable now.. you can handle it to your Modal etc..
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```