# Pass PHP variables to jQuery Popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a PHP page with dozens of variables and arrays. I need access to most of them in a little popup the page generates. I've seen an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646787/pass-php-variable-into-jquery-popup), but I don't understand it. What is the script he's loading with json? Is that something custom written with all of the php variables? That won't work for me as the variables are dynamically assigned from the results of an XML document loaded from an API. The XML document can be different with each pull.

**Basic overview of the page:** 
  The site loads XML from an API based on the user request. I use Xpath to grab the xml, and then iterate through it to create an array of arrays. I then use another loop to create named arrays with product variables. Some of the product variables are pulled into single variables, and I write functions with both the arrays and variables. How can I make all of this data available to the popup?

The page itself is a grid of product packages. The user needs to be able to customize the product quantities within the package, and a popup seemed like the most elegant way to manage this. The popup has a picture of the package, a short description, and a list of the products with a quantity text box that the user can change(or it least it will have those things when I get access to the php variables). After the user makes changes to the quantities, I will pass the changes back to the main page form with jQuery.

I'm using the [bPopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) plugin to manage the popup. The popup loads an html file into an empty div. I can change the extension to PHP, if need be.The empty div looks like this, and it's at the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
    <a class="b-close">x<a/>
</div>
```

and the jQuery to call it is:

```
// Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
// Encapsulation
// $ is assigned to jQuery
;(function($) {

    // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

      // Binding a click event
      // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
      $('#economy-button').bind('click', function(e) {

          // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
          e.preventDefault();

          // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
          $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
              loadUrl: 'lib/page-parts/economy.html' //Uses jQuery.load()
          });

      });

   });

})(jQuery);
```

So how do I pass all of the variables from the parent page into the popup page? The simplest solution is desired. I don't have any experience working with json and very limited experience with ajax. If your answer requires either of those, then please explain it to me like I'm five years old. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I find a bit difficult to understand exactly your problem. It seems to me that the since you load the popup content from another html into a div... in the parent page (bPopup uses ajax I belive).... there is no popup all your data IS IN THE PARENT... you don't need to "pass it". if you post an example of some of this variable you produce with PHP maybe I can do something more for you.

Comment: Yeah I thought it would pass too. Maybe I should have the content already in the hidden div instead of loading it into the div from an outside file. I was just using the outside file for the sake of sanity. The code is already getting quite long.

Comment: Actually yeah, I just tried that and I have access to all the php variables. I'll just use this method I guess unless someone can offer a solution.